# Complex conjugate as ordered pair

Tags: complex-numbers

let $(a,b) \in \mathbb{C}$, the complex conjugate of $(a,b)$, as ordered pair, is $(a,-b)$... is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is one way to view complex conjugation.

Comment: @T.Bongers.. thans soo much!! :)